# ERC721 token sended to previous metamask selection

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-721

First, I want you guys know I'm a newbie with SC, I follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPbgjPPC1d0

I have this strange bug where tokens are sended to my previous selection inside metamask, i.e.

1. Run the app
2. Open metamask and Select the network and the address I previous imported from ganache
3. Select address 1, Change it to address 3 and refresh the app with F5
4. I confirm that the address shows up in the dom (Like the tutorial)
5. Click the button that mints one token, confirm that correct address on metamask popup, F5 again
6. Token is not there, repeat step 5
7. Token shows up correctly
8. Change to address 1 and there's the first token that I minted

Heres the source code of App.js:

```
async componentWillMount() {
    await this.loadWeb3()
    await this.loadBlockchainData()
  }

  async loadWeb3() {
    if(window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
      await window.ethereum.enable()
    }
    else if(window.web3){
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
    }
    else{
      window.alert("Non ethereum blablabla")
    }
  }

  async loadBlockchainData() {
    const web3 = window.web3
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()//aqui me traigo el array de cuentas de metamask
    this.setState({ account: accounts[0]})//la 0 es la que esta activa

    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId()
    const networkData = Color.networks[networkId]
    if(networkData){
      const abi = Color.abi
      const address = networkData.address
      const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address)
      this.setState({contract: contract})
      const totalSupply = await contract.methods.tokensOfOwner(accounts[0]).call()
      if(totalSupply==null)
        this.setState({totalSupply: 0})
      else
        this.setState({totalSupply: totalSupply.length})
      for (var i = 1; i <= totalSupply.length; i++) {
        const color = await contract.methods.colors(totalSupply[i-1]._hex).call()
        this.setState({
          colors: [...this.state.colors, color]
        })
      }
      console.log(totalSupply)
    }
    else{
      window.alert("Non contract on this network")
    }
  }

  mint = async (color) => {
    const web3 = window.web3
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    this.state.contract.methods.mint(color).send({from: accounts[0]})
    .once('receipt', (receipt) => {
      this.setState({
          colors: [...this.state.colors, color]
        })
    })
  }
```

Contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";

contract Color is ERC721Enumerable {
    
    string[] public colors;
    mapping(string => bool) _colorMintedAlready;

    constructor() ERC721('Color', 'CLRS') public{
    }

    function mint(string memory _color) public{
        require(!_colorMintedAlready[_color]);
        colors.push(_color);
        uint _id = colors.length;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, _id);
        _colorMintedAlready[_color] = true;
    }

    function tokensOfOwner(address _owner) external view returns(uint256[] memory ownerTokens) {
        uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);

        if (tokenCount == 0) {
            // Return an empty array
            return new uint256[](0);
        } else {
            uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](tokenCount);
            uint256 totalCats = totalSupply();
            uint256 resultIndex = 0;

            // We count on the fact that all cats have IDs starting at 1 and increasing
            // sequentially up to the totalCat count.
            uint256 catId;

            for (catId = 1; catId <= totalCats; catId++) {
                if (ownerOf(catId) == _owner) {
                    result[resultIndex] = catId;
                    resultIndex++;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```